# Comments on Overridden method in Java

Tags: java, methods, comments

Should we comment the overridden method or not? If yes, then whether the comment will be a Java Doc or simple comment?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607641/javadoc-comments-vs-block-comments for the second part of your question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@SimonC's answer explains how the javadoc utility generates "inherited" documentation for overridden methods.

You can also put explicit javadocs in an override method and they will take precedence over the inherited javadocs.  Furthermore, if you put the `{@inheritDoc}` tag in the override method's explicit javadocs, the inherited comments will be included at that point.

To answer this:

> Should we comment the overridden method or not?  If yes, then whether the comment will be a Java Doc or simple comment?

In my opinion, if the override method refines the documented semantics (contract) of the overridden method (or ... heaven forbid ... breaks the contract), then this deserves to be documented in the override method's javadocs.  However, if the differences are merely "implementation details", then simple comments (or no comments) are more appropriate.

(However, the practice of including a "non-javadoc" comment that refers the reader back to the overridden method's javadoc is, IMO, a waste of screen real-estate ... when I am reading the source code.)

Answer (score 8):

From [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html):

> Automatic re-use of method comments
>
> You can avoid re-typing doc comments
>   by being aware of how the Javadoc tool
>   duplicates (inherits) comments for
>   methods that override or implement
>   other methods. This occurs in three
>   cases: When a method in a class
>   overrides a method in a superclass
>   When a method in an interface
>   overrides a method in a superinterface
>   When a method in a class implements a
>   method in an interface In the first
>   two cases, if a method m() overrides
>   another method, The Javadoc tool will
>   generate a subheading "Overrides" in
>   the documentation for m(), with a link
>   to the method it is overriding.
>
> In the third case, if a method m() in
>   a given class implements a method in
>   an interface, the Javadoc tool will
>   generate a subheading "Specified by"
>   in the documentation for m(), with a
>   link to the method it is implementing.
>
> In all three of these cases, if the
>   method m() contains no doc comments or
>   tags, the Javadoc tool will also copy
>   the text of the method it is
>   overriding or implementing to the
>   generated documentation for m(). So if
>   the documentation of the overridden or
>   implemented method is sufficient, you
>   do not need to add documentation for
>   m(). If you add any documentation
>   comment or tag to m(), the "Overrides"
>   or "Specified by" subheading and link
>   will still appear, but no text will be
>   copied.