# Java code commenting best practices

Tags: java, android, comments

I have finalized my Java/Android project and now I need to comment the codes (mainly classes and important methods).

I need to do it by following the best industrial standards as later if someone else need to modify, it should be well staright forward.

I read many articles and found 3 main types of java commenting styles.

1. Single line comment (//.....)
2. Block comments (/* ....... */)
3. Doc comments (/** ....... */)

I read mainly about the option 2 and 3. [Stack overflow discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607641/javadoc-comments-vs-block-comments)

So I thought of going with 2nd option as I don't need to generate HTML docs as these classes are not going to use by any other people and this is the implementation of this app.

Wonder what are the best practices in block commenting indicating "return" type, "parameters" and "breif description" of the method or class.

Would like to hear the best industrial standard practices of the java code commenting.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: It's not a duplicate with this as I am asking about the best industrial way to go with option 2 in my question.... Basically if a method has several parameters how to explain about each (Like @param is there in doc comments). Also the return types etc....

Comment: fair enough, comment removed.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend going with the 3rd option, because if someone looks at your code for example through an IDE which supports the JavaDOCs (e.g. Eclipse), it'll show relevant information about the objects he/she examines when he/she hovers over an element that interests him/her.

This way, the developer will not have to open the actual class source file to understand what it's contract is, what does it do, or perhaps what Exceptions you have to lookout for when using it.

You can link relevant classes/methods together via JavaDOC hooks like @see.

Personally, I usually like to put DOC comments at least on my class, and public methods, for private methods I don't usually see much use for DOC comments since I don't usually generate the JavaDOC HTML. Other than DOC comments I usually tend to use the single line comments, and only use block comments when I feel like 1 sentence will not be enough to express what I wanted to, or when the print margin restrictions come into play.

Comment: Thanks Ceiling Gecko. Good explanation. But in my case most of the classes and methods will never need to generate HTML Docs. Most of the codes are this application specific and no use of HTML docs at all... That's why I am looking to go with option 2 and a proper way to explain the parameters and return types as option 3 has (@param, @return). Thanks.

Comment: The point was that you asked about **industry** standard. Your fellow developers are letting you know about how others *besides* yourself will expect to see the source code. Another way is to look at actual open source projects that have comments to follow their practice. Doc style in definitely the preferred way for descriptions of a chunk of code and line style is best for single items in those chunks.

Answer (score 3):

For explanation about API use javadoc /** ... */

For explanations inside code use //

For commenting out several code lines use /* ... */

Comment: Thanks Pavel Bernshtam. Ya, as you say I will need several lines commenting option mainly because it's not going to be an API. And also these classes and methods are this application specific and not going to use by any 3rd party application......... What I am exactly looking is what the best way to describe a method completely. For example in doc comments it has (@param, @return etc..). The way to do this using block comments (/* sevela lines */)....

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) standard with the javadoc [tag conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag) (3rd option). Why:

- It is a widly used standard that every java progammer should easy understand.
- Most IDEs support the javadoc standard and tags. The IDE show relevant information and helps developer
- If you don't need to generate HTML now, maybe you need to do it later.
- It is the "industrial standard", as you ask for.
- By describing classes and methods, you describe the API of you programm. The standard for describing the API is Javadoc, so use it.

The first and second option is more for comments directly on code lines. Not for description of the classes and methods.